# How to determine what handler is executing for a .NET MVC url?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

We have a .NET MVC 5 application that is designed to run on two separate domains.  Basically there is the main version and a "lite" version of the application.  We have custom route constraints that detect the routes that should be run to different controllers.  The majority of the system is identical throughout with the same routes.  Our WebApi calls are working in the "lite" version of the application, but are returning an 200 status code with an empty response body on the "full" version of the application.  Furthermore, we can attach the debugger and determine that the controllers are getting executed in the "lite" version, but not in the "full" version.  We have stuck breakpoints in every constructor we could find and we cannot determine what is actually getting run in the "full" version of the code.  We have used the famous RouteDebugger from https://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/ and we can determine that the route IS being hit, but the controller is never executed.  We can look at the Application_BeginRequest and EndRequest and determine that the request is coming in and being processed, but the response is always 200 with an empty body on those urls in the "full" version.

What is the best way to track down what is actually being executed, and why that is being executed instead of the controller, even though the route is matching?

Comment: so do you have 2 domains, each running an identical route configs? can you show us your route configs?

Comment: We ultimately found that it was caused by some middleware that was hard-coded to filter out anything that didn't have the "lite" URL.